# Get all child pages in wordpress without the parents

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress site has pages like this:

```
-home
   -about
   -history
-contact
   -office1
   -office2
   -office3
-solutions
   -corporate
```

The menu structure is also the same. How can I get only the child pages as an array, so that I can get something like this:

```
-about
-history
-office1
-office2
-office3
-corporate
```

I want all the pages with depth 1. Right now I am using this function:

```
$pagelist = get_pages('sort_column=menu_order&sort_order=asc');
$pages = array();
foreach ($pagelist as $page) {
   $pages[] += $page->ID;
}
```

But here I also get the parent pages. I can do a loop to remove parent pages from the array, but is there any wordpress solution to get what I want in one function call?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) object :

```
$children_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'           => 'page',
    'orderby'             => 'menu_order',
    'order'               => 'ASC',
    'post_parent__not_in' => array('0')
));
$children_pages = array();
if($children_query->have_posts()){
    while($children_query->have_posts()){
        $children_query->the_post();
        $children_pages[] = get_the_ID();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
var_dump($children_pages);
```